# move mouse with python on windows 7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mouse-cursor

How can I move the mouse cursor in python 2.7 on Windows 7?

```
def MoveMouse(x,y):
    #move mouse cursor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you need is Win32api.

```
import win32api
def move_to(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
```

Comment: Works amazingly well